# init() function Public instance vs Private Instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Someone pointed out in my work that I have made an init() function public and that I should make it private. Currently my function looks something like

```
that.init = function(){
  //my Code
}
that.init();
```

From what I have looked up so far, it would be better to declare it this way. Please correct me if I am wrong

```
function init() {
//my code
}
init();
```

I would like to know the difference, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: take a look at closure

Comment: What are you initialising? Can you provide the complete example.

Comment: Hi @DmitriPavlutin I am initializing a $http.get call

Comment: Why declare a function just to immediately invoke it and then supposedly never call it again in the first place...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following cases:

**1) Declare a function which is available in current controller scope:**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function() {

  function init() {
  //my code
  }
  init();

});
```

This way the `init()` function will be available only within controller's function scope (not Angular's `$scope`). `init()` is private.
It is the correct approach when `init()` is used only within controller.

**2) Declare the function as a property of the controller's `this` context**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function() {

  this.init = function() {
     //my code
  }
  this.init();

});
```

In this case any code that has access to controller's context `this` will be able to use or even modify the `this.init()` function. In simple words it is public.
You can later use `init()` in the view, for example:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
   <button ng-click="ctrl.init()">Init me</button>
</div>
```

Check this article about [scopes and context](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/) and some recommendations from [Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#function-declarations-to-hide-implementation-details).

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from your code is, you are using `controllerAs` syntax in your `angularjs` application.

```
that.init = function(){
  //my Code
}
that.init();
```

Here `that` points to your `vm`.

```
function init() {
//my code
}
init();
```

There is no subtile difference in both. I would prefer the latter because its not attached to `vm`. You would attach something to `$scope` or `vm`, when you want to make it available to your view, else do with a `function declaration`.

Private `members/methods` in javascript:

```
function Vijay(){
    var myPrivateVar; // this is private

    var private_stuff = function()   // Only visible inside Restaurant()
    {
        myPrivateVar= "some value";
    }

    this.public= function()   // is visible to all
    {
        private_stuff();
    }

}
```

You can read more on private members/method here: 
http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html